# How I can set gap in Vertical BoxSizer?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

How can I set gap in Vertical BoxSizer? What's in the Vertival BoxSizer the similar or alternative method of `SetVGap` (which sets the vertical gap (in pixels) between the cells in the sizer) in GridSizer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several ways to add blank space in a sizer.

```
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(widget, proportion=0, style=wx.ALL, border=5)
```

The code above will add the widget with a 5 pixel border on all sides of it. If you want to put some space between two widgets, you can do one of the following:

```
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
sizer.Add(widget, proportion=0, style=wx.ALL, border=5)
sizer.AddSpacer(10) 
# or sizer.Add((0,0))
sizer.Add(anotherWidget, proportion=0, style=wx.ALL, border=5)
```

The nice thing about doing sizer.Add((0,0)) is that you can add it with a proportion of 1 (one) if you want and that will push all the following widgets to the bottom. I use it to give me a little more control over widget placement.

See also http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html

Comment: "doing sizer.Add((0,0)) is that you can add it with a proportion of 1 (one)" Simpler way of doing this is to call AddStretchSpacer
()

Comment: I always forget about that one. For some reason, I've seen more examples of the (0,0) one than the AddStretchSpacer(). I guess it's up to the programmer.

Comment: This works but the space added is white. When I add spacer I need to be able to see the background color from the parent container. How can I do this?

Comment: The bg color shouldn't be white. You should post a question on stack with a small, runnable example along with what OS and wxPython version you are using.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean a vertical box sizer, like so

```
wxBoxSizer * szr = new( wxVERTICAL );
```

The following call will add 10 pixels of 'vertical gap'

```
szr->AddSpacer(10);
```

In Python, I guess it would look something like this

```
szr = wx.BoxSizer( wxVERTICAL )

... add stuff above gap

szr.AddSpacer(10)

... add stuff below gap
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no gap parameter in `wx.BoxSizer`s (do there is in GridSizers as you said). The way to create a gap is by setting the border in your widgets. This can be done with the styles: `wx.ALL`, `wx.BOTTOM` and/or `wx.TOP`.

For example:

```
szr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
szr.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.TOP|wx.BOTTOM|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5)
```

will add a centered widget (a button in my code) in the Box with 5-points border at the top and bottom.

Show if you write:

```
vgap = 5
szr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
szr.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.TOP, vgap)
szr.Add(self.button_2, 0, wx.TOP, vgap)
szr.Add(self.button_3, 0, wx.TOP, vgap)
```

you get 3 buttons gapped similarly to what you would have with `SetVGap` and you can aswell control the separation between slots by setting vgap.

As other answers indicate you can also insert separators between your widgets to obtain the same effect but this seems to me cleaner (no addditional "sizer.add" lines) if what you want is something equivalent to grids vgap.

Comment: why the downvote? what is wrong in the answer? The OP is asking how to put the equivalent to a gridsizer gap in a boxsizer. Spacers are also valid but borders are more similar to gaps than spacers which are more like additional widgets (they are added and *fill* additional slots).

Answer (score 2):

May also be interesting : find the title "wx.BoxSizer" in

http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/